# Loop through stored procedures with input and output parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops

I am looking for a script for look through stored procedures with input and output parameters.

I use the following script to manually input `processdate` and get the `date id` as output. Every time I just change the `@ProcessDate` to process.

Does anyone have a better way to write a loop to run this stored procedure and set the `@ProcessDate` from `2017-04-30` to `2017-08-31`?

Appreciate it!!

```
Declare
    @ProcessDate datetime,
    @Date_ID int 

select @ProcessDate = '2017-04-29'

exec casp_Dim_Date @ProcessDate, @Date_ID output
```

Comment: Are you doing something with @Date_ID?

Comment: I just have the SP to convert Processdate (datetime type) to Date_ID (int type)

Comment: what's the result of your execution in the above example? i.e. what does '2017-04-29' become?

Comment: Yes but if you want to call this stored procedure in a loop what are you doing with @Date_ID each time? Does it get saved somewhere, ignored, what?